# reusing setup and teardown with against-background in midje

Tags: unit-testing, testing, clojure, midje

I have a number of midje facts that have setup/teardowns that are almost, but not quite, entirely the same.

```
(against-background [(before :contents (setup!)) (before :contents (data)) (before :facts (set-access)) (after :contents (teardown!)]
  (facts "about this thing i am testing "
    ; ...
  ))

(against-background [(before :contents (setup!)) (before :contents (data)) (before :facts (set-other-access)) (after :contents (teardown!)]
  (facts "about this other thing i am testing "
    ; ...
  ))
```

I would like to wrap the backgrounds into something reusable and preferably paramterizable so I can reuse them, but having trouble doing so. Midje tells me anything other than the above is not the expected background form.

Comment: I guess this is because `against-background` is a macro that parses the passed vector at compile time itself rather than emitting code that use the passed vector at run time

Comment: The best places for answers to questions like these is http://groups.google.com/group/midje?pli=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Midje does not have the ability to do what you ask built into it.  If you would like this, consider adding it as an issue here: 
https://github.com/marick/Midje/issues?sort=updated&direction=desc&state=open&page=1

A solution is to create your own macro to do this. (untested)

```
(defmacro against-my-background [docstring & body]
  `(against-background [(before :contents (setup!)) 
                        (before :contents (data)) 
                        (before :facts (set-access)) 
                        (after :contents (teardown!)]
     (facts ~docstring
       ~@body )))

;; usage
(against-my-background "about this thing i am testing"
  (fact (foo) => :bar)
  (fact (foo) =not=> :baz))
```